# Unable to save Excel file after modification using Ruby & win32ole

Tags: ruby, excel, win32ole

Using http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/classes/WIN32OLE.html as a guide I have written the following:

```
require 'win32ole'
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
excel.visible = false #Setting this is 'true' doesn't reveal anything
workbook = excel.workbooks.open('C:\myspreadsheet.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.worksheets('sheet1')
worksheet.Activate

data = worksheet.UsedRange.Value
p data.size #This works! - My spreadsheet has 3987 rows.
p data[3932] #This works, too! - I can "see" row 3932.

worksheet.Rows(3932).Insert #Insert a row above row 3932

data = worksheet.UsedRange.Value
p data.size #Returns 3988! This would seem to indicate that I've successfully added a row since it was just 3987.

workbook.saved = true #Save the workbook and quit.
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
excel.Quit()
```

When I open the Excel spreadsheet after all of this it is unchanged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `Saved` property of a `Workbook` object to `True` does not cause the workbook to be saved. That property is used as a flag to show whether a workbook has unsaved changes. Setting it to `True` is a simple way of preventing the "Do you wish to save..." dialog appearing when Excel is closed.

To actually save the workbook, you need the `Save` method of the `Workbook` object. This method doesn't return anything so I would assume that `workbook.Save` would do the trick (I have no experience of Ruby, unfortunately, so can't be 100% sure on that)

Comment: I added "workbook.Save" immediately after "workbook.saved = true" and everything went great.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, out of curiosity, where could I have gone to find this information myself? It's great that I can get an answer on stackoverflow, but isn't there documentation or a reference someplace for something like this? I've looked, but the only thing I could find was the link at the top. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: All of the details of the Excel object model are on MSDN. `Workbook.Saved` is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196613.aspx The example code for most items will be in VBA but you should get enough information to use it in Ruby

Comment: Thank you for the link! That's great stuff. I'm not sure that I would have ever found that.